# onsuccess and always mod_header Apache2.4 and cache control

Tags: aem, apache2.4, mod-headers

Apache2.2 this rule worked fine for curl -I when content is not cached.

```
Header always set Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400"
```

Moving to 2.4 cache control header is missing on curl -I ,but works fine for GET request when content is pulled from AEM and stored inside cache, backend is Adobe AEM and apache has AEM dispatcher module.

To make it work i have add .

```
`Header always set Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS}` == 200"
```

Header always set fixes the issue , why this behavior change how can i troubleshoot this issue , also  i read somewhere like apache have some internal table of responses headers i am not able to find any on documentation . if this is not satisfied then Header set (on success) wont work.